# How to create edittable tables with aws amplify and dynamodb

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Does anyone know how to make tables editable on reactjs, where the datasource is from a dynamodb table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API category in Amplify for this, and have API Gateway run a Lambda that performs your business logic for reading and writing to DynamoDB. The AWS Mobile CLI has this pattern built in:

```
$ npm install -g awsmobile-cli
$ cd my-app
$ awsmobile init
$ awsmobile enable cloud-api
```

Then if you were trying to edit it would probably be a POST using the API category:

```
async function postData() { 
    let apiName = 'MyApiName';
    let path = '/path';
    let myInit = { // OPTIONAL
        body: {}, // replace this with attributes you need
        headers: {} // OPTIONAL
    }
    return await API.post(apiName, path, myInit);
}

postData();
```

The React Sample on AWSlabs demonstrates this: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-react-sample

Comment: Thank you Richard.

I just got this setup, do you know how to make the tables edittable with a delete button? I'm new to react, and trying to get data from dynamo then allow users to edit/delete it in a table. 

I am using react-table, however they do not have a delete button implementation. I tried react-data-grid, but they made it so hard to customise the table and said it's not something they support out of the box. So react-table was what I stuck to.

Comment: Table permissions are controlled by the Lambda function, so really it's just a question of if the IAM role that the Lambda function is configured with has permissions to perform an UpdateItem (edit action) or DeleteItem (delete action) to that DynamoDB table. Once you've got that working then you'll call the appropriate API Gateway resource tied to this action when an `onClick` handler fires in your React application.

Comment: Alright, I definitely understand now because of you.

Thanks Richard